# DELL Inspiron 7520 and amd radeon driver 13.1: How can I switch video cards?

Tags: ati, dell, hybrid

I have wanted to know can you make switching on the Inspiron 7520 using an AMD HD 7730m and an Intel 4000hd.

Dell sent me two scripts:   
Script 1:

```
#turn off discrete graphics card
echo '\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.GFX0.DOFF' > /proc/acpi/call
# turn it back on
echo '\_SB.PCI0.PEG1.GFX0.DON' > /proc/acpi/call
```

Script 2:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone link Intel Ubuntu drivee
cd acpi_call
make
sudo insmod acpi_call.ko
./test_off.sh :
```

Basically, what this is trying to do is to shut down the card I don't need but I am not good enough to make those script work. May I have your help?

Comment: `git clone link Intel Ubuntu drivee` doesn't make sense. After `git clone` there should be a URL to the repository location, which will probably end with `/acpi_call.git`.

Answer (score 0):

Install [this version of Ubuntu (12.04.1)](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201203-10678/). After installation, just update your system and install additional drivers (GUI will guide you). 
I have the same laptop computer. It works perfect (drivers, brightness, switchable graphics, etc.)